# type initializer for system.management.wminetutilsHelper threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to connect to another computer using this code:

```
String FullComputerPathName = @"\\mycomputer\";

ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Password = "some_password";
options.Username = "some_user";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(FullComputerPathName, options);
scope.Connect();
```

And got the exception:

> The type initializer for 'System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper' threw
> an exception. Inner Excepction: ArgumentNullException: value cannot be
> null.

The log trace:

> "at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(IntPtr ptr, Type t)
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer[TDelegate] (IntPtr ptr)
>
> at System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper.LoadDelegate[TDelegate](TDelegate& delegate_f, IntPtr hModule,String procName)
>
> at System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper...cctor()"

I don't understand what went wrong .

Thank you

Comment: Please show the full stack trace - that's likely to help work out what's going on.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I added the full stack trace.

Comment: That doesn't show the stack trace for the inner exception, which would give more information about what shouldn't be null. Basically include *everything* you can from the log.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same issue on 2008 R2.

**tl;dr**: Install a recent version of the .net framework (installing 4.7 worked for me)

Longer version:
I'm assuming that you are using `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` in a .net core project.

After decompiling the `System.Management.dll` assembly, I found that it is looking for the .net framework path, and is using the file `v4.0.30319/wminet_utils.dll` and is loading 50 methods, but if one is not found, it fails. In my case, it was missing `"GetErrorInfo"` and `"Initialize"`.

I don't know which .NET framework version I had, but updating to 4.7 solved my issue.